# has webapp2 been deprecated in app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, webapp2

I've been trying to find a question like this for ages, couldn't find this so I'll ask it.
I have tried pip installing and PYTHONPATH but it hasn't worked

`import webapp2`
but every time it gives me:
`Unable to import 'webapp2' pylint(import-error)`
anybody else had this problem? have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

`webapp2` is part of the `google-cloud-sdk` library and is only for `Python 2.7`. Check if you have it installed.

If you're on a Mac, check

`/Users/<user>/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/`

If you're on a Windows machine, check

`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\`